# How to make an AJAX search

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to make an AJAX search for a website.

HTML:

```html
<form id="search" method="post" action="search.php">
    <input type="text" name="search" />
    <input type="image" name="submit" alt="search" src="images/buttons/search.gif" />
</form>
```

```js
$(function() {
    var search_text = '';
    $('form#search input[name=submit]').click(function() {
        search_text = $('form#search input[name=search]').val();
        $.get('../search.php',{ s: search_text });
        return false;
    });
});
```

In the *search.php* file I have the following:

```php
<?php
    $search = $_GET['s'];
    if (isset($_POST['submit_x'])) {            
        $search = $_POST['search'];
        $search = str_replace(' ','',$search);
        $search = strtolower($search);

        if($search == 'kingbabychosenheart' || $search == 'chosenheart' || $search == 'beltchosenheart') {
            echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=chosen_heart.php'>";
        } else {
            echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=not_found.php'>";
        }       
    }       
?>
```

But this doesn't work. What else do I have to do to make this work?

Thanks

Comment: when I write sth in the search box and click search, nothing happens, so I'm wondering maybe I need to post sth back from the search.php to the html page that contains the form.

Comment: you are returning a META element, that will be invisible. Echo a P tag and see what goes...

Comment: after echo("<p>the search has been found</p>"); still nothing happens,
it just stays in the html page, the <p> tag doesn't appear either.

Comment: Also, in your php script, you are testing against a variable that is not existing: if (isset($_POST['submit_x'])) {
  add an input with name="submit_x"

Comment: and change it to $_GET instead of $_POST.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of, your form will not be usable with Javascript disabled.  I hope you know that, since your form has no submit element *per se*.

With that in mind, you should use the `submit()` event and attach it to the form, then trigger that event when the image is clicked.

```
$(function() {
    var search_text = '';
    $('#search').bind('submit',function() {
        search_text = $('input[name=search]', $(this)).val();
        $.get('../search.php',{ s: search_text });
        return false;
    });

    $('#search img[name="submit"]').click(
        $('#search').trigger('submit');
    });
});
```

Or better still, use the [jquery form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/).

Comment: ah sorry about that. Didn't notice. Corrected.

Comment: If the OP is trying to redirect the user, you may have been right before: `$('#search').submit();` may work here, because the form has `action="search.php"`.

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that `get` has no callback - you ping the server, but do nothing with the reply:

```
$.get("/search.php", { s: search_text }, function(data){
  alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to send data through AJAX, you must cancel the event by returning false in submit event in the form, to avoid send double data;

```html
<form id="search" method="post" action="search.php" onsubmit="return false;">
  <input type="text" name="search" />
  <input type="image" name="submit" alt="search" src="images/buttons/search.gif" />   
</form>
```

```js
$(function() {
  var _myform = $("form#search");
  $(_myform).find("input[name='submit']").click(function(e) {
     e.stopPropagation();
     var search_text = $(_myform).find("input[name='search']").val();
     $.get("../search.php",{ s: search_text });
  });
});
```

in the PHP code, if you send data via GET, you will not receive anything for POST.

For that you should do the following:

```js
$(function() {
  var _myform = $("form#search");
  $(_myform).find("input[name='submit']").click(function(e) {
     e.stopPropagation();
     var search_text = $(_myform).find("input[name='search']").val();
     $.post("../search.php?s="+search_text,{ "submit_x": "" });
  });
});
```